# I want to append() to a nested list, but end up appending to all my lists, why?

Tags: python, loops, indexing, append, nested-lists

I have my object:

```
def NewShip(length, width, height):
    frontLeft = [] #ship[5]
    frontRight = [] #ship[6]
    midLeft = [] #ship[7]
    midRight = [] #ship[8]
    backLeft = [] #ship[9]
    backRight = [] #ship[10]
    for i in range(88):
        x = []*18
        frontLeft.append(x)
        frontRight.append(x)
        midLeft.append(x)
        midRight.append(x)
        backLeft.append(x)
        backRight.append(x)
    return [length, width, height, [], dict(), frontLeft, frontRight, midLeft, midRight, backLeft, backRight]
```

And inside each of the "frontLeft" etc i want to add a lists called "Containers", that looks like this:

```
[id, 20, 2, cargo]
```

There should only be 18 of these containers inside each of the 88 lists inside each of the "backRight" etc.

Thsi is what i have tried:

```
def loadContainerToShip(ship,container):
    newWeight = container[4]
    lightestArea = getLightestArea(ship) #returns the index of the lightest area
    lightestStack = getLightestStack(ship[lightestArea]) #returns index of the lightest stack(list)
    loaded = False
    for i in range(len(ship[lightestArea][lightestStack])):
#here i want to insert the new container if the container "below" in the tack is heavier
        oldWeight = getTotalWeightContainer(ship[lightestArea][lightestStack][i])
        if oldWeight <= newWeight:
            #insertContainerOnShip
            ship[lightestArea][lightestStack].insert(i,container)
            ship[3].append(container)
            addContainerToDict(ship,container)
            loaded = True
            break
    if not loaded: 
        print(ship[lightestArea][lightestStack])
        ship[lightestArea][lightestStack].append(container)
        ship[3].append(container)
        addContainerToDict(ship,container)
```

When i do this i insert each container into all of the 6 lists referred to in the NewShip decleration.
So alle the lists are the same and also it does not add another container into a list, it overwrites is? WHY AND HOW CAN I FIX

Comment: You appended the list you created as `x` to many other lists. If you change `x`, it will change everywhere since it is the same object.

Comment: `x = []*18` is a list of 18 references to the same inner list.

Comment: **I change it. Now i get only one container per 88 list, but one of the 88 lists has 512 elements in it? there must be something wrong with the way i append or inserts because the result should be 88 * 6 lists with around the same amount of containers. But it is one with far to many?** @Kla

Comment: @KlausD. what do you think?

Comment: @matszwecja what do you think?